# cast object to type without creating new variable

Tags: c#, reference, compilation

This question is a curiosity of mine, so I'm not look for a away around this just an explanation.

I've been wondering why a new variable has to be created when you are casting.

It's the sort of thing I would have thought the compiler could work it's magic on as I am casting to a known type.

So that code like this could be written shorter.

```
DataTable dataTable = RetrieveDataTableFrom(whereEver);

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.rows)
{
    if (row.ItemArray[0].GetType() == typeof(myTypeA))
    {
         MyTypeA myTypeA = (myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0];
         myTypeA.myCustomProperty = "dem works";
    }
}
```

Like this, where I just edit the property more directly.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.rows)
{
    if (row.ItemArray[0].GetType() == typeof(myTypeA))
    {
         (myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0].myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
    }
}
```

Edit: Oh so a mistake in my understanding! Whoops, I thought it didn't make sense... ha.
A little extra, would you consider either method (assuming correct amount of parentheses used) more clear/readable than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's because you're actually not casting quite the right way in your second example.

```
((myTypeA)(row.ItemArray[0])).myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
```

When casting, it's often important to be as clear as possible about what exactly you're trying to cast. In this case, adding a couple sets of parenthesis indicates to the compiler that you don't wan to cast `row` or `row.ItemArray` or `row.ItemArray[0].myCustomProperty`, but `row.ItemArray[0]`, which is actually of type `myTypeA`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.rows)
{
    if (row.ItemArray[0].GetType() == typeof(myTypeA))
    {
         ((myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0]).myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
    }
}
```

or you can use LINQ

```
foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row.ItemArray[0].GetType() == typeof(myTypeA)))
{
   ((myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0]).myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
}
```

Comment: Always interesting to see alternative LINQ solutions +1

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add parentheses and it will work:

```
((myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0]).myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
```

Answer (score 1):

A new reference will still be created in the second case, it will just be at a lower scope.  Over the course of evaluating that complex statement a number of very short lived temporary variables will be created to store intermediate values; the result of your cast will be one of them.

Now that temporary object won't need to live for the entire lifetime of the `if` statement, the way the first example does (even though in practice the odds of a GC collection half way through that statement is...low), but that is unlikely to matter.

Also note the cast has nothing to do with this.  Just writing:

```
object first = new object();
object second = first; //the reference is copied here
```

copies a reference.  There need be no cast to do that.

Copying a reference is also not a slow operation.  In fact, it is among the single fastest operations that can possibly be performed by a computer, that of taking a single word of memory and moving it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add parentheses;

```
((myTypeA)row.ItemArray[0]).myCustomProperty = "dem breaks";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(row.ItemArray[0] as myTypeA).mycustomproperty = value
```